# Erase those values that already exists in other key's values in map c++

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stdmap

Consider I have a map with values as mentioned below:

```
std::map<int, std::set<int>> myMap;
key 0: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
key 1: 1,2,3,4,5,6
key 2: 4,5,6,7
key 3: 6,7
```

Now, I want to erase all those values in key 0 that exists in other keys following it. Similarly for key 1 and so on.
So, the final output (myMap) should look like this:

```
key 0: 8,9,10
key 1: 1,2,3
key 2: 4,5
key 3: 6,7
```

As far as I know, it is not so easy to search by values in map. And for my code, it is not feasible to search by values as my data is extremely large. This would be time-consuming.

Is there a better way to do this without going through each value in each of the following keys to remove the common values?

Comment: how did they get into the map?

Comment: The values are actually basic blocks for every loop that I have in an application. I get it from a supporting tool. While inserting it is not possible to have a check, as I use data given from another tool.

Comment: How do you intend to find out whether _x_ exists in any _key_ without actually examining those _keys_? That's simply not possible according to the laws of physics. You could speed it up by creating a sort of index in a second container, if you liked, and if it were worth the added memory/time cost of creating said index - if you're doing this once, it's unlikely.

Comment: It really might be easier to do this on the fly as you _use_ the data, but without knowing what you're trying to do, it's impossible to say. An [MCVE] would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::set<int> to_remove;
for(auto&& e:backwards(myMap)) {
  std::set<int> r;
  std::set_difference(
    r.second.begin(), r.second.end(),
    to_remove.begin(), to_remove.end(),
    std::inserter(r)
  );
  std::copy(r.second.begin(), r.second.end(), std::inserter(to_remove));
  r.second = std::move(r);
}
```

where `backwards` is:

```
template<class It>
struct range_t {
  It b, e;
  It begin() const { return b; }
  It end() const { return e; }
};
template<class C>
auto backwards( C& c )
-> range_t< typename C::reverse_iterator  >
{
  return {c.rbegin(), c.rend()};
}
template<class C>
auto backwards( C const& c )
-> range_t< typename C::const_reverse_iterator >
{
  return {c.rbegin(), c.rend()};
}
```

which makes iterating over a container backwards quick and easy.

This is O(nlgn), while your solution was O(n^2lgn).